# Custom CSS overridden - JSF Richfaces

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

In my application, they have overridden the CSS classes of richfaces with a CSS configuration to customize the look and feel. It was working fine till i made the below mentioned changes,

1. Implemented a new message box,
2. Implemented a new .xcss file for the message box look and feel.
3. Upgraded all the richfaces jars(api, impl, ui) from 3.3.1 to 3.3.3.

New message box and the xcss is implemented separately and i had not changed any existing CSS configuration. But the custom CSS classes which is already in use, has been overridden by richfaces CSS. Is this because of the upgraded richfaces jar in my build path.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue after upgrading from 3.3.0 to 3.3.3.

With 3.3.0 a <rich:tab> would render as
<td class="dr-tbpnl-tb rich-tab-header dr-tbpnl-tb-act rich-tab-active">

With 3.3.3 it renders as
<td class="rich-tab-header rich-tab-active">

So, the dr- classes have disappeared. Since the doc (section 5.10.3) still states that those classes should be rendered, I guess it's either

- some configuration that needs to be done, but I didn't find any doc on that
- a bug